# understand difference between encode() and bytearray

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

If I have :

```
my_str = '0xfe'
str_enc = my_str.encode()
>> str_enc
b'0xfe'
>>type(str_enc)
<class 'bytes'>

a_lst = [my_str]
byte_arr = bytes([int(x,0) for x in a_lst])
>>byte_arr
b'\xfe'
>>type(byte_arr)
<class 'bytes'>
>>str_enc == byte_arr
False
```

Shouldn't these 2 be equal? I'm developing a Client application using sockets and the common theme to send data is to use the send() function:

```
send('mydata'.encode())
```

since they are not equal does it mean I won't be able to send the bytearray directly?

```
send(byte_arr)
```

Comment: Start with an analogy. Do you understand why `10 != '10'`?

Comment: Also, try printing `len(str_enc)` vs `len(byte_arr)`

Comment: Why should the two be equal? And why does it mean that sending bytes over sockets is not possible. Why not using encode and decode on each corresponding side of the connection.